# What kind of game is prisonblock? Any open source that I can learn the math behind it?

Tags: mathematics

What kind of game is prisonblock?  Any open source that I can learn the math behind it for user actions/gameplay?

Answer (score 3):

As it says in the browser title, [Prison Block](http://www.prisonblock.com/) is a "FREE prison RPG game" (RPG meaning Role-Playing Game). It also appears to be multiplayer and therefore can be considered a "[MMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_game)" or "[MMORPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmorpg)", albeit browser-based (in contrast to popular MMOs such as World of Warcraft).

I recommend looking at the source of [Legend of the Green Dragon](http://www.lotgd.net/) ([sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lotgd/)). I'm not sure if it's still being updated, but I remember finding it several years ago and being impressed by it; so much so, that I made my own little web-based multiplayer game ([Magbor](http://rickyc.org/magbor/), [sf proj](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magbor/) - warning, it's messy and not too impressive!). LotGD is a web-based multiplayer RPG like Prison Block, and completely open source.

Comment: great that is a perfect link!

Comment: LOGD is still going strong. I was writing modules for it a year back, proliferated over a lot of sites. Very strong community.